# How to change default scaling governor back to ondemand

Tags: kernel

After playing with GRUB profiling and installing preload, default scaling governor suddenly becomes 'performance' not 'ondemand'. I tried to enable /etc/init.d/ondemand service, but nothing changes - after reboot or resume, governor is always 'performance'. Do anybody knows what happened and how to revert old behaviour.

I'm using HP 6710s laptop.

Comment: Uninstall cpufreqd. Use only cpufreq-utils.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can Manually set the governor by running the ***cpufreq-set*** command (as root).

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -g ondemand
```

To install `cpufreq-set`:

```
sudo aptitude install cpufrequtils
```

> ***cpufrequtils*** includes a daemon which allows users to set the desired scaling, governor and min/max clock speeds for all processor
>   cores at boot-time.  Before starting the daemon, edit
>   `/etc/default/cpufrequtils` as root, selecting the desired governor and
>   setting the min/max speed for your CPU(s), for example:
>
> ```
> /etc/conf.d/cpufreq
> ```
>
> ```
> #configuration for cpufreq control
> # valid governors:
> #  ondemand, performance, powersave,
> #  conservative, userspace
> governor="ondemand"
> # valid suffixes: Hz, kHz (default), MHz, GHz
> min_freq="1GHz"
> max_freq="2GHz"
> ```

**Source:** [archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_Frequency_Scaling)

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. Probably when I have some time, I will try to find why this happened at all.

Comment: It's /etc/default/cpufrequtils on Ubuntu, not /etc/conf.d/cpufreq. And the variables (as seen in /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils) are MAX_SPEED, MIN_SPEED and GOVERNOR.

Comment: @elmicha I'll verify, and edit as needed.  Thanks :)

Comment: `sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -g ondemand` will just apply to the frequency of the first CPU or core. So, for example, on a dual core system, you have to run `sudo cpufreq-set -c 1 -g ondemand` next, so it takes effect for both cores.

Comment: Do all your CPUs at once: `for cpu in $(seq 0 $(($(nproc) -1))) ; do echo sudo cpufreq-set -c $cpu -g ondemand ; done`

Comment: on `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1231 v3` I have `Invalid argument` for anything other than `performance`, e.g. `ondemand` or `conservative`.

Comment: @Patryk Maybe those aren't supposed on your cpu, which makes some sense for a server/workstation cpu. I'm sure there is a command to get all the supported ones.

Comment: Oh, my bad, the basic `cpufreq-info` already lists the supported ones. Check the line `available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave` (here also on a Xeon E3 cpu). Edit: And I wrote "supposed" instead of "supported" in my last comment...

Comment: @Mitch So, did you verify ?

Comment: @JohanBoule To change governor per CPU go to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`, and change it to the desired governer.  Do that for all available CPU`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command to change governor:

```
cpufreq-selector -g ondemand
```

With this command, you don't need root privileges to change governor. Just add this command to *Startup Applications...* to change governor on login.

Comment: Problem was in Jupiter which changes governor at each restart/resume even if program isn't running.

Comment: You saved my day, I edited that command and use it with Cuttlefish to dim light and switch the governor on change of power ;) Man youre great!

Answer (score 0):

Under Xubuntu, you also need to disable `ondemand` task by command:

```
sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
```

the system boot cpu as `GOVERNOR="performance"` mentioned above