# cpu frequency stays at the top even with ondemand or powersave governors

Tags: 12.04, cpufreq

The fan goes lower but the /sys/devices...../cpuinfo_cur_freq and scaling_cur_freq list the highest frequency. core i5 can go down to 1.2Ghz according to cpuinfo but watching the time_in_state shows it middle-of-the-roading it, with time only growing at 2ghz.
what do I do? I want low low low low freq and power.

Comment: I will suggest you to use these settings http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 0):

You can [Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681) read the full configuration

> Removing default Ubuntu cpu frequency config

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove
```

Then you can use this post [How to change default scaling governor back to ondemand](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149271/how-to-change-default-scaling-governor-back-to-ondemand)

> Just keep it in mind that you need **powersave**

#### powersave       Run the cpu at the minimum frequency

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils -y
```

Comment: You need to use some utility to stay on powersave mode ...