# How to restore the cpu frequency defaults or to align the frequency at will?

Tags: command-line, cpu, frequency

I really new at ubuntu and linux so i am not capable of understand the following:

```
usage: 

     update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> remove
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> defaults [NN | SS KK]
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> start|stop NN runlvl [runlvl] [...] .
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
        -n: not really
        -f: force
```

So, how is the right command to restore the cpu frequency defaults or
to align the frequency at will?

This is because I installed TLP and used

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove
```

but it turned out that the heating increased comparing TLP without the remove.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo update-rc.d ondemand defaults` will make the `ondemand` script start on every boot.

This [entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149271/how-to-change-default-scaling-governor-back-to-ondemand) explains how to change the default frequency scaling governor.

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04 through 17.04  you can install [`indicator-cpufreq`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=indicator-cpufreq&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) 
either through the software center or with `sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq` which auto-runs at startup and allows for choosing specific supported frequencies as well as Conservative, OnDemand, Powersave, and Performance settings. If you don't want to reboot to start it you can launch it in the background with `indicator-cpufreq &` and it should place an indicator next to the network indicator on the top panel (at least in Unity)