# Overwhelming Fan on AC

Tags: power-management, fan

It's been 1 year since I am dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows 10. Learned many beautiful things of Ubuntu yet I am weak in hardware related side. Though in other OS my computer works quiet, fan is always on when using Ubuntu. I just read almost all posts in the forum about this. Installed `lm-sensors`, `psensor`, `tlp`, `thinkfan`. Changed every single BIOS setting to prefer battery life rather than performance. Tried solutions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04) but did not work out, as well. Nothing solved problem. I think I need a hand this time. Just hesitated doing this to prevent causing damage:
[See the answer part](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425909/how-do-i-control-my-fan-speed)

An observation which might make sense: When I plug out charging cable fan stops generally but I don't know what to do to connect the dots. I can provide any additional detail if you can tell me what to write into terminal or so. Thanks, in advance.

**Edit**: output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

What I've tried so far:

```
$ sudo tlp bat
TLP started in battery mode.
$ sudo pm-powersave true
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub # Added GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!Windows 2012"
```

Answers in this:

[Power Savings and Performance Modes on Ubuntu System](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203303/power-savings-and-performance-modes-on-ubuntu-system)

[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 all done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persistent High-Fan Speed Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516067/persistent-high-fan-speed-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @ElderGeek actually, I tried that solution also. It did not work for me. Also that question says nothing about being OK in fan speed when plugging out the charging cable. Would you please remove the duplicate sign?

Comment: Is your system set to run in performance mode when plugged in and power saving when not? http://askubuntu.com/questions/203303/power-savings-and-performance-modes-on-ubuntu-system or http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: Does the battery get warm when charging? I seem to remember a recall on batteries that overheated when charging.

Comment: @ElderGeek tried both tlp and pm-powersave utility. It only stops when I plug out, as before.

Comment: Could you [edit] into your post the commands and the output of the utilities that you tried? It might provide some clues. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: What's the year, make, and model of your computer?

Comment: @MikeWaters Toshiba PSPN2U-003003 Satellite E45-b4200, 12/05/2014

Comment: Would you be so kind as to include in your [edit] what you changed in `/etc/default/grub` ? thank you

Comment: Interesting kernel parameter choice. What's the output of  `uname -a`  Thank you!

Comment: @ElderGeek Linux <name> 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What happened when you changed /etc/default/grub as in my edited answer?

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: @ElderGeek I boot on windows and changed the section : on AC, maximum performance to Battery Optimized . Then fan started to work OK, I mean it was rotating when CPU is pushing itself. Maybe this could be a hint. I'd like to do same thing for Ubuntu though I tried many thing to do that. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may be facing a dangerous situation. A large number of Toshiba laptops were sold with batteries that could overheat causing a burn hazard and possibly catch fire. Please for your own safety check to see if you have one of these batteries!

The affected battery packs included in this recall have part numbers that begin with G71C (G71C*******). Part numbers are printed on the battery pack. A complete list of battery pack part numbers included in this recall can be found on Toshiba’s website. 
The laptops directly affected by the recall, (Portege, Satellite, and Tecra laptops, sold between June 2011 through Nov. 2016.)

**Note:** Toshiba cautions that other computers may be affected if their owners purchased extra battery packs or had their batteries replaced during servicing.

**Edit:** If your issue isn't caused by an inflammatory battery your issue is likely being caused by lying to the kernel. issue the command `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and change 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=!Windows 2012"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`

Edit: Based on your comment regarding Windows it sounds to me like you want to have easy control over performance vs. power saving. See my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/740840/225694) The choice that corresponds to Windows Battery Optimized is Powersave

Sources:

https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2017/Toshiba-Expands-Recall-of-Laptop-Computer-Battery-Packs

https://consumerist.com/2017/01/04/toshiba-adds-83k-laptop-batteries-to-recall-over-continued-overheating-burn-hazards/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Common_Kernel_Options

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I checked it in Toshiba's website. Is is not affected model.

Comment: Check the battery part number itself to be safe. See the Note in my answer.

Comment: Yeah did that from entering battery's serial number. Result is clear.

Comment: Excellent. I was worried about you.